# Java the stream tomap with lambda expression give me error

Tags: java, lambda, casting, java-8, java-stream

when i try to compile this line of code:

```
public Map<String,Long>countBranchesPerMunicipality(){
    return mappamun.values().stream()
            .collect(toMap(m->m.getName() ,  m->m.getBranches().size()));
}
```

it give me the error:

> cannot convert from `Map<Object,Object>` to `Map<String,Long>`.

Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: What type has `mappamun`? Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 3):

```
int size();
```

It is what a `List<E> extends Collection<E>` returns. Autoboxing turns `int`s into `Integer`s, but not into `Long`s. That is why you got the compilation error.

There are 2 possible options:

1. Changing the return type to `Map<String, Integer>` *(preferable)*;
2. Casting the size to `long`: `(long)m.getBranches().size()`.

Comment: how i can cast to long in that stream? Thank you

Comment: @SamuraiJack, why did you stop on the second option?

Comment: Because it's an exercise of school and i can't change the type of Map

Comment: Could you add it to the question? We could find a better solution. Anyway, the cast is `(long)m.getBranches().size()`

Answer (score 0):

The `getBranches()` method returns very probably a `Collection` instance and `Collection.size()` returns an `int` not a `long`.

So you should change the return type of the method from

```
Map<String,Long>
```

to  :

```
Map<String,Integer>
```

And of course `m.getName()`  should return a String.